# Integration by parts on compact, non-orientable Riemannian manifold with boundary

Tags: integration, riemannian-geometry, laplacian, geometric-measure-theory, manifolds-with-boundary

Let $(M,g)$ be a compact Riemannian manifold, *not necessarily* orientable or without boundary. Let $\mu$ be a normalized volume measure on $M$ and $u$ be a smooth function on $M$. In some notes that I received, following equation is claimed by integration by parts:

$$ \int_M e^u \Delta u \,d\mu = - \int_M \lvert\nabla u\rvert^2 e^u d\mu $$.

I have some trouble following it. As far as I know, the following "product rule" holds in that case (even if $M$ is unorientable):

$$\nabla \cdot (fX) = \nabla f\cdot X + f \nabla \cdot X $$

for any smooth function $f$ and smooth vector field $X$ on $M$. Can anyone confirm this with some reference, as I didn't find a good one? In the above case that would mean,

$$\nabla\cdot (\nabla e^u)=\nabla\cdot (e^u \nabla u)= e^u \lvert \nabla u\rvert^2 + e^u\Delta u.$$

Thus, this yields

$$ \int_M e^u \Delta u d\mu = - \int_M \lvert\nabla u\rvert^2 e^u d\mu + \int_M \nabla\cdot (\nabla e^u) d\mu.$$

Now, I do not quite see how to get rid of the second integral on the right hand side.
If $M$ were orientable, I think the divergence theorem would give

$$\int_M \nabla\cdot (\nabla e^u) d\mu = \int_{\partial M}(\nabla e^u)\cdot dS,$$

which would be zero if the manifold is without boundary. Yet, if $M$ is not orientable and does have a boundary, I don't see how to get the initial formula. Can this really hold in the afore-mentioned generality?

Comment: Maybe these functions are compactly supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The divergence theorem works in the nonorientable case as well, it just requires the use of densities rather than differential forms. See for instance theorem 16.48 of Lee's *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds*.

The boundary term won't generally vanish without further conditions on $u$. It should be easy to come up with a counterexample on a simple case like $[0,1]$.